# Can I import extra Python modules to repl.it?

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

I am a beginner in Python, and I have been using [repl.it](http://repl.it) to code. I noticed that the math module can be imported using this website, but modules like numpy and sympy cannot. Is there some way to add these to repl.it?

Comment: `math` is part of the [Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html). I don't think there are extra packages installed on that site